# using brainfloat16 or bf16 in python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I need to use bfloat16 in Jupyter. Numpy and python versions are upto-date. How do I install it or use bf16 in jupyter?

I have tried upgrading both jupyter and numpy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tensorflow: register numpy bfloat16 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354058/tensorflow-register-numpy-bfloat16-extension)